# How to add specific symbols from static library

Tags: build, compilation, linker

I am trying to use `--whole-archive` option, but it seems to not work with `-Xlinker`. How can I add this option by using -`Xlinker` ?

Here is the whole story:
I write a main program A, and several shared libraries B1,B2,etc. main program will use dlopen to load these shared libraries at runtime. I compile main program A linking with ALL the possible static libraries used by main program (S1,S2...etc) or shared libraries (S3,S4...etc). then I compile shared library without static library.
When calling dlopen, the program fail because of undefined symbol in shared library. this symbol does exist in static library S3, but I can not find it in symbol table of main program.

So I add --whole-archive option when compiling main program, but the symbol still not exists in final binary. how can I add this symbol to main program while it is not direct used in main program.

Comment: Assuming you are using GNU binutils, `--whole-archive` works perfectly fine with `-Xlinker`. You might want to clarify your question: what command line you used, what led you to believe the `--whole-archive` didn't work, etc.

Comment: thanks I have made the whole story more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I add --whole-archive option when compiling main program

You still have not answered the question: what command line you used. Adding linker options when *compiling* in generally pointless: they only matter when *linking*.

The correct link line for the situation you described is (assuming you are using GCC on a UNIX/ELF system):

```
 gcc -rdynamic -o exename main.c \
   -Wl,--whole-archive -lS1 -lS2 -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Explanation of important points:

1. The `-rdynamic` is needed so that symbols defined in the main
   executable are visible to `dlopen`ed shared libraries.
2. Libraries should follow sources on the link line (order of libraries and sources [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html)).
3. Libraries which you want to link in entirely should be surrounded by `--whole-archive` and `--no-whole-archive` options.

Comment: Actually I am using a tool to generate Makefile and I can not control the order of --whole-archive, -l*, --no-whole-archive. thus, as you point out, it is because the static library I want to link in entirely is not following --whole-archive option. thanks, it is very helpful